# set per point legend in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to do something quite simple, which is to have 4 different colored columns on a column chart, and to include each of these as a separate item in the legend.

So far the best way I have found to do this is to to parse null values for each of my categories where I don't want them to show, and then allow grouping so they can overlap centrally on each point of the X Axis.

This does work but I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same rather than including 0 values in my series?

Included is a fiddle so you can see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/mkw04uy4/1/

The data section shows what I am doing.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Category Testing'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: ['Cat 1', 'Cat 2', 'Cat 3', 'Cat 4']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Count'
        }       
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0,
            grouping: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Cat 1',
        data: [230, 0, 0, 0]
    }, {
        name: 'Cat 2',
        data: [0, 800, 0, 0]

    }, {
        name: 'Cat 3',
        data: [0, 0, 670, 0]

    }, {
        name: 'Cat 4',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 1200]
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: And I guess you still want to be able to hide/show that individual point using the legend, right?

Comment: That is not important really to be honest. This way works OK it's just a bit odd to have to do it the way I do :)

Comment: Well with 0 values is fine,so I think that parsing to null values are not required.